# Squid upgrade HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, squid

I want to use squid to upgrade HTTP request to HTTPS using my own certificate in order to do a client handshake with a server (a reverse proxy) that requires mutual authentication.

How can I configure that in squid?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate must be a CA certificate, e.g. have the CA flag and the appropriate key usage.

Comment: I tried to give the ssl-bump the path to CA certificate that signed the client certificate and it's key like this :
    http_port 3128 ssl-bump cert=/path/to/CA-certificate.pem key=/path/to/ca-certificate.key
But still have the same error

Comment: first: ssl bump is not for upgrading http to https but for SSL interception (man-in-the-middle, both sides SSL). If this is what you do please show the relevant sections of your CA-certificate.pem which show that it is a CA.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't need SSL interception, so what can i use to add a client certificate to the request. Iam new to squid

Comment: I don't think you can do this with squid.